# How to add tooltips to dat.gui

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dat.gui

Has anybody found a way to add `tooltips` to the dat.gui entries?

It seems there is no `class` assigned to them so how can I select them?

Comment: I added a changerequest at https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/issues/251

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add this capability to dat.GUI yourself. Here are some guidelines and an example solution.

Entries are represented with classes that are inherited from the `Controller` class. Each controller has a private member `__li`, that represents its `<li>` element in the gui. You can extend the `Controller` prototype and add a `title` function, that will add, update or remove the `__li`'s title attribute.

Here is the snippet:

```js
/* dat.GUI copies the prototype of superclass Controller to all other controllers, so it is not enough to add it only to 
the super class as the reference is not maintained */
var eachController = function(fnc) {
  for (var controllerName in dat.controllers) {
    if (dat.controllers.hasOwnProperty(controllerName)) {
      fnc(dat.controllers[controllerName]);
    }
  }
}

var setTitle = function(v) {
  // __li is the root dom element of each controller
  if (v) {
    this.__li.setAttribute('title', v);
  } else {
    this.__li.removeAttribute('title')
  }
  return this;
};

eachController(function(controller) {
  if (!controller.prototype.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    controller.prototype.title = setTitle;
  }
});


// demo
var Dummy = function() {
  this.foo = 12
};
Dummy.prototype.bar = function() {
  console.log('1');
};

var gui = new dat.GUI();
var d = new Dummy();
gui.add(d, 'foo').name('Foo').title('Foo\'s title');
gui.add(d, 'bar', 1, 13, 1).name('Bar').title('Bar\'s title');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry it has taken me so long. busy with other projects. where should I add this code. in dat.gui source code or in my code?

Comment: This code snippet is supposed to be used with your own code without changes to the dat.gui library. It could be solved more elegantly if done directly in the dat.gui's source.

Comment: I added a change request at https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/issues/251